# How to remove objects from ManyToMany Field in Django Rest Framework neasted serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can successfully add a new object(s) into `notification_days` but what is the most idiomatic way to handle removing any object(s)?

models.py

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
    (0, 'Mon'),
    (1, 'Tue'),
    (2, 'Wed'),
    (3, 'Thu'),
    (4, 'Fri'),
    (5, 'Sat'),
    (6, 'Sun'),
)

class WeekDay(models.Model):
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_day_display()


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    notification_days = models.ManyToManyField(WeekDay)
```

serializers.py

```
class WeekDaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    day_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = WeekDay
        fields = ['id', 'day', 'day_display']

    def get_day_display(self, obj):
        return obj.get_day_display()

class CompanySettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notification_days = WeekDaySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = [
            'name',
            'notification_days'

        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        notification_days = validated_data.get('notification_days')

        for day in notification_days:
            day_id = day.get('id', None)

            if item_id:
                if not instance.notification_days.filter(pk=day_id).exists():
                    week_day = WeekDay.objects.get(pk=day_id)
                    instance.notification_days.add(week_day)

        return instance
```

api.py

```
class CompanySettingsAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsCompanyAdmin, )
    serializer_class = CompanySettingsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return Company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Sample GET response:

```
{
    "name": "Django",
    "notification_days": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "day": 0,
            "day_display": "Mon"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "day": 1,
            "day_display": "Tue"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I send PUT request with the following body, new week day is successfuly added:

```
{
    "name": "Django",
    "notification_days": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "day": 0,
            "day_display": "Mon"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "day": 1,
            "day_display": "Tue"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "day": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only ids on the request.
And use `.set()` method to update the relations.

PUT Request:

```
{
  "name": "Django",
  "notification_days_ids": [
    1,
    2,
    4
  ]
}
```

Serializer:

```py
class CompanySettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notification_days = WeekDaySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    notification_days_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        write_only=True,
        source='notification_days',  # just to make it looks a little bit better
        queryset=WeekDay.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = [
            'name',
            'notification_days',
            'notification_days_ids',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'notification_days' in validated_data:  # to handle PATCH request
            instance.notification_days.set(validated_data['notification_days'])

        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks! I got AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`. So I added: https://pastebin.com/zLBXAM60 is there something I can improve?

Comment: Also, you can try to use `queryset=WeekDay.objects.all().only('pk')` to save a little bit of time. But it is very optional.

Answer (score 2):

First clear the old notification days

```
instance.notification_days.clear()
```

and add the new ones from put request

```
instance.notification_days.add()
```

It helped me